# Разбор QuerySet Django

Tags: python, django

Есть переменная которая хранит данные с запроса бд

`counts_item = Item.objects.values('name','price').annotate(Count('name')).distinct()`

Она при запросе она получает `QuerySet` вида

`{'name': "'Panasonic'", 'price': 46900.99, 'name__count': 7}, {'name': "'LG TV", 'price': 52000.0, 'name__count': 1}, {'name': "'LG'", 'price': 1000.01, 'name__count': 7}`

Так как это не 1 словарь, а их несколько  как их выводить в шаблоне html?

Comment: Ну, обычным циклом выводить?

Comment: В шаблоне циклом, например, так: `{% for x in li %}{{ x }}{% endfor %}`.